# Did the Oracle give Smith the capability to replicate himself?

Tags: the-matrix, agent-smith

I am curious to know if there is anything mentioned in the Matrix canon that indicates that the Oracle had given Smith the capability to replicate himself.

I am wondering if she felt that Smith would need this special capability in order to take over the Matrix and to threaten Machine City so that it would feel compelled to give humans their freedom.

[image]

Did the Oracle give Smith the capability to replicate himself?

Comment: The ability to replicate himself came from Neo, surely?

Comment: @Valorum, I don't know. If Neo did have to the power to replicate himself then he should have done so because there could have been an army of Neos fighting an army of Smiths.

Comment: That's precisely what he did. He jumped into Smith and (inadvertently) copied over some of his own code. Smith them co-opted that ability to merge his code and override other entities within the Matrix.

Comment: @Valorum, I suppose that occurred. Yet, it brings up the question as to what exactly happened to the machine located back in the Machine City which was Agent Smith. Did that machine and its AI die when Neo destroyed Smith in the Matrix? If so, how did Smith come back to life unless someone in Machine City brought him back to life. Whoever brought Smith back to life could have given Smith the capability to replicate himself.

Comment: @Valorum Smith already contained the code to replicate himself into blue pills, but once Neo corrupted his programming, he could replicate himself in anyone he jabbed his hand into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to think that the Oracle gave Smith the ability to replicate himself.

For one, the Oracle's purpose has nothing to do with regulating the abilities of Agent programs. The Architect described the Oracle as

> an intuitive program, initially created to investigate certain aspects of the human psyche. If I am the father of the Matrix, she would undoubtedly be its mother.
>
> <sub>**[transcript for *The Matrix Reloaded*](http://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix-reloaded/transcript/)**</sub>

The Oracle herself noted that a program that is not doing what it is supposed to do is *subject to deletion or exile*:

> The Oracle: The [programs] doing their job, doing what they were meant to do, are invisible. You’d never even know they were here. But the other ones, well, we hear about them all the time.
>
> Neo: I’ve never heard of them.
>
> The Oracle: Of course you have. Every time you’ve heard someone say they saw a ghost, or an angel. Every story you’ve ever heard about vampires, werewolves, or aliens is the system assimilating some program that’s doing something they’re not supposed to be doing.
>
> Neo: Programs hacking programs. Why?
>
> The Oracle: They have their reasons, but usually a program chooses exile when it faces deletion.
>
> <sub>**[transcript for *The Matrix Reloaded*](http://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix-reloaded/transcript/)**</sub>

The Oracle was never an Exile so she only did what she was meant to do -- which involves the human psyche and prediction of the future, not regulating the abilities of the Agent programs.

Second, the Oracle indicated that Smith's growing abilities were the result of the *system* (not her) trying to balance the One's growing abilities. Furthermore, the Oracle clearly opposed Smith, who she saw as threatening to destroy the future. Both of these points are apparent from her conversation with Neo in *The Matrix Revolutions*:

> Neo: The Architect told me that if I didn’t return to the Source, Zion
> would be destroyed by midnight tonight.
>
> Oracle: *rolls eyes* Please…
> You and I may not be able to see beyond our own choices, but that man
> can’t see past any choices.
>
> Neo: Why not? Oracle: He doesn’t
> understand them – he can’t. To him they are variables in an equation.
> One at a time each variable must be solved and countered. That’s his
> purpose: to balance an equation.
>
> Neo: What’s your purpose?
>
> Oracle: To
> unbalance it.
>
> Neo: Why? What do you want?
>
> Oracle: I want the same
> thing you want, Neo. And I am willing to go as far as you are to get
> it.
>
> Neo: The end of the war. *Oracle nods* Is it going to end?
>
> Oracle:
> One way, or another.
>
> Neo: Can Zion be saved?
>
> Oracle: I’m sorry, I
> don’t have the answer to that question, but if there’s an answer,
> there’s only one place you’re going to find it.
>
> Neo: Where?
>
> Oracle:
> You know where. And if you can’t find the answer, then I’m afraid
> there may be no tomorrow for any of us.
>
> Neo: What does that mean?
>
> Oracle: Everything that has a beginning has an end. I see the end
> coming. I see the darkness spreading. I see death. And you are all
> that stands in his way.
>
> Neo: Smith.
>
> Oracle: *nods* Very soon he’s
> going to have the power to destroy this world, but I believe he won’t
> stop there; he can’t. He won’t stop until there’s nothing left at all.
>
> Neo: What is he?
>
> Oracle: He is you. Your opposite, your negative, the
> result of the equation trying to balance itself out.
>
> <sub>**[transcript for *The Matrix Revolutions*](http://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix-revolutions/transcript/)**</sub>

The Oracle opposed Smith and explained that she is helping Neo because

> We’re all here to do what we’re all here to do. I’m interested in one thing, Neo, the future. And believe me, I know – the only way to get there is together.
>
> <sub>**[transcript for *The Matrix Reloaded*](http://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix-reloaded/transcript/)**</sub>

The Oracle had no reason to grant Smith the ability to replicate himself, nor did she have the ability to do that since it is not her purpose. What she *did* have the ability to do is predict that the system would attempt to balance the growing power of the One and adjust her plans accordingly -- i.e., to use the virus Smith as part of her plan to help the One end the war once and for all.

Comment: those are very good points that you made. It's clear to me now that she would not have given Smith this capability.